# react append to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm using a reactstrap dashboard theme

The side menus are populated by an array of menu objects.

I wish to:

1. populate the array from XHR
2. set the raw data blob as a global variable for the rest of the app to use.

Here is what I'm trying ...

```
class ClusterItems extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      apiurl: ' ',
      clusterItems: [
        {
          name: 'Clusters',
          title: true,
          wrapper: { element: '', attributes: {} },
          class: ''
        },
        {
          divider: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    const apiurl = 'http://validapiurl/clusters'
    axios.get(apiurl).then(results => (
      this.state.clusterItems.push({
        icon: 'icon-layers',
        name: item.clusterName,
        url: '/clusters' + item.clusterName + '/instances'
      })
    ))
  }
}
```

The part that I'm missing is how to `export this.state.clusterItems` as an ARRAY and how to do the global export of the data blob `clusters`.

Comment: If you want to add the results to state so that you can then use it, you can do something like `results => this.setState({ clusterItems: this.state.clusterItems.concat(theItemYouWantToAdd)})`

Comment: why exactly do you need a global? with react you can pass the data down to a child component as props. Thats typically whats done with react. If you want APP state however you can use a state library like redux or MobX. Describe *why* youd like a global though and maybe we can point you in the right direction :)